# Cannot hide tab bar in child view controller

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

In my containerView that embeds a UINavigationController. To that navController 2 viewControllers are connected. See the image bellow.
[image]

Everything works well, except for both childViewControllers get a TabBar that i cannot hide no matter what i try. Here's what it looks like on device. 
[image]
Blue is the background color of the containerView
Here's how i'm trying to hide from the childViewControllers

```
    self.tabBarController!.tabBar.hidden = true
    self.navigationController!.toolbarHidden = true
    self.navigationController!.tabBarController!.tabBar.hidden = true
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
```

and from the containing viewcontroller:

```
    self.childViewNavigationController.toolbarHidden = true
    self.childViewNavigationController.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: false)
    self.childViewNavigationController.tabBarController!.tabBar.hidden = true
    self.childViewNavigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
```

The blue area is 49 points high, that's why i 'm thinking it's reserved for a tab bar.

Answer (score 0):

The issue left unresolved. Fortunately the main viewcontroller needed to be presented, instead of pushed, so childview's navigationcontroller didn't inherit anything from the main viewcontroller's navigationcontroller and the area for the tab bar disappeared.